# Looping through the objects in my nested embeded document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to make a forum where users can comment on posts but I'm having a hard time getting it to display the comments on the post page in most recent comment order.

This is my data:

```
_id: 60d99b6a95e1a8243c9a60f1
postTitle: "adsf"
postText: "afdsfdsafdsfds"
postUsername: "testuser"
date: 2021-06-28T09:50:34.617+00:00
comments: [
        {
            _id: 60dabeb40c99410ad015988d
            author: testuser2
            text: asdfasdf
            commentDate: 2021-06-29T07:44:28.977+00:00
        }
    ]
```

I want to do something like this:

```
router.get('/forum/:id', async (req,res)=>{
    const newPost = await Createdpost.findById(req.params.id)
    res.render('show', {comment: await newPost.comments.find().sort({commentDate: 'desc'})})
})
```

And then loop through all the comments sorted by date in descending order in ejs:

```
<% comment.forEach(comment => { %>
    comment.text
<% }) %>
```

I hope what I'm trying to do makes sense, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What's the issue though? How does it fail?

Comment: It just says undefined is not a function, which I guess is because I'm using the find() function wrong but I'm not sure what alternative I should be using to get the result I want in this method.

Comment: You can try to make a single query on the posts collection to return the desired output. See the usage of [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) to sort the comments array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mongoose `Model.find().sort()` method is for sorting documents when returning them from the database.

`NewPost` is already a document, so you can't call `find` or `sort` on it.

You can use the javascript's [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to sort the array that has already been returned:

```
res.render('show', {comment: newPost.comments.sort((a,b) => a.commentDate < b.commentDate ? 1 : 0)})
```